# Mongoose group by category on nested level

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

Hello everyone I am new to the node js community

I am facing a problem with 2nd level filtering of categories. Please help me with how to filter second-level grouping.

My raw data as given below

```
Clothing
    Shoe    
        PUMA
Clothing
    Shoe    
        NIKE
Clothing
    Watches 
        TIMEX
Electronics
    Laptop
        DELL
Electronics
    Monitor
        HP
```

and I am searching for like this

```
Clothing
    Shoe    
        PUMA    
        NIKE
    Watches 
        TIMEX
        
Electronics
    Laptop
        DELL
    Monitor
        HP
```

my JSON is like below, what will be the grouping to get the result like above

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "618a094d36143c2c807f0124",
            "parentId": null,
            "title": "Clothing",
            "level2": {
                "_id": "618a098636143c2c807f0129",
                "parentId": "618a094d36143c2c807f0124",
                "title": "Shoe",
                "level3": {
                    "_id": "618a09ba36143c2c807f012e",
                    "parentId": "618a098636143c2c807f0129",
                    "title": "PUMA"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": "618a094d36143c2c807f0124",
            "parentId": null,
            "title": "Clothing",
            "level2": {
                "_id": "618a098636143c2c807f0129",
                "parentId": "618a094d36143c2c807f0124",
                "title": "Shoe",
                "level3": {
                    "_id": "618b820ebd59b4c554d880f3",
                    "parentId": "618a098636143c2c807f0129",
                    "title": "NIKE"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": "618a094d36143c2c807f0124",
            "parentId": null,
            "title": "Clothing",
            "level2": {
                "_id": "618a099136143c2c807f012b",
                "parentId": "618a094d36143c2c807f0124",
                "title": "Watches",
                "level3": {
                    "_id": "618a09d436143c2c807f0130",
                    "parentId": "618a099136143c2c807f012b",
                    "title": "TIMEX"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": "618a095f36143c2c807f0126",
            "parentId": null,
            "title": "Electronics",
            "level2": {
                "_id": "618a09ed36143c2c807f0132",
                "parentId": "618a095f36143c2c807f0126",
                "title": "Laptop",
                "level3": {
                    "_id": "618a0a0336143c2c807f0134",
                    "parentId": "618a09ed36143c2c807f0132",
                    "title": "Dell"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": "618a095f36143c2c807f0126",
            "parentId": null,
            "title": "Electronics",
            "level2": {
                "_id": "618a0a2136143c2c807f0136",
                "parentId": "618a095f36143c2c807f0126",
                "title": "Monitor",
                "level3": {
                    "_id": "618a0a2e36143c2c807f0138",
                    "parentId": "618a0a2136143c2c807f0136",
                    "title": "HP"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/q-HR7vZiZ6f) what you are looking for? Would be helpful if you can provide a concrete expected output example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Collection
  .find({},"collectionName"))
   .populate({
      path: "categories",
      model:"Category",
      select:"categoryName subCategories",
      populate:{
        path:"products",
        model:"Product",
      }
   }).then((products)=>{
    res.status(200).json(products);
   });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.